# eign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.LinkedHashMap]

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to use FeignClient to connect to a REST service in a Spring Boot application. But the service is failing to load. Please find the details below and suggest.

I am using <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>

```
**pom.xml**

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>

@FeignClient(value = "SpringBootREST2", url = "http://localhost:9050/orders/v1/getMovieDetails/{movieId}")
public interface RestFeignService {

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Movie getMovieDetailsFeign(@PathVariable("movieId") Integer movieId);

}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class SpringCloudFeignApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private RestFeignService restFeignService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudFeignApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Movie movie = restFeignService.getMovieDetailsFeign(100);
        System.out.println(movie);
    }
}
```

**Exception**
Caused by: feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.LinkedHashMap]